# What geographical areas are NOx sensitive/limited (with regard to ozone)?

Tags: atmospheric-chemistry, ozone, air-quality

Have there been any air quality modeling studies regarding the locations where ozone is considered "NOx limited" (increasing NOx increases ozone)  or "NOx sensitive" (decreasing NOx increases ozone)? The larger the domain of the study, the better.

Comment: I'd think such a model would closely follow the regions of high natural VOC content as being regions that are NOx limited in photochemical ozone production.

Comment: It is related with the ratio of NOx/VOC. If you want to figure out the spatial distribution of NOx sensitive/limited region in a large area, the satellite data (HCHO/NOx) could shed some light for you.